# SQL query to combine duplicates and sum

Tags: sql

**UPDATE**: *sorry for the confusion. "table" was not my actual tablename, I have updated it with the correct name and also more info about the error below.*

I have a table called TrackingNumbers with two columns. The orderid column data sometimes repeats as there are multiple shipments per order (I didn't design the database):

```
orderid shipment_cost
1021    5.34
1021    7.83
1022    5.19
1023    5.59
```

How can I add all the shipment_cost values when the orderid repeats using a SQL query? So I would like the query results to look like:

```
orderid shipment_cost
1021    13.17
1022    5.19
1023    5.59
```

My best guess is that it goes something like this:

```
SELECT orderid, SUM(shipment_cost) FROM TrackingNumbers GROUP BY orderid
```

But that gives me an unspecified SQL error. Unsure if it is my query or the silly proprietary app. Thanks for any advice!

---

**UPDATE 2:** So it appears my query was OK according to the answers and I also just double-checked on my own MySQL server, comes back OK. It must be the application's fault (Volusion). They have a crappy little interface for running custom reports and it appears to be wrapping my SQL query with extra stuff. The error from Volusion:

```
SQL Error: SELECT * ,17041 as RecordCount 
           FROM (SELECT TOP 10 * 
                 FROM (SELECT TOP 10 orderid, SUM(shipment_cost) 
                       FROM TrackingNumbers 
                       GROUP BY orderid ORDER BY ) 
                 SUBSEL ORDER BY ) 
           PAGESEL ORDER BY
```

And if I add an ORDER BY like

```
SELECT orderid, SUM(shipment_cost) 
FROM TrackingNumbers 
GROUP BY orderid 
ORDER BY orderid ASC
```

since that's what it seems it wants:

```
SQL Error: SELECT * ,17041 as RecordCount 
           FROM (SELECT TOP 10 * 
                 FROM (SELECT TOP 10 orderid, SUM(shipment_cost) 
                       FROM TrackingNumbers 
                       GROUP BY orderid 
                       ORDER BY orderid ASC) 
                 SUBSEL ORDER BY orderid DESC ) 
           PAGESEL ORDER BY orderid ASC
```

Guess I will have to see if Volusion's support can provide any clues. Thanks again!

---

**Update3:** Of course Volusion support is unhelpful even though I told them this query works on another SQL server and it's obvious their interface is mangling it. Looks like I will have to import the data into my down database and manipulate it there.

Comment: If that's your exact query, you need to escape `table` since it's an SQL keyword.

Comment: Your query looks OK to me, what is your full SQL error? It may be caused by something else.

Comment: @Nick: If I understand the OP correctly, they must have been prevented from seeing the full error message by the "silly proprietary app".

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I have updated my post with some additional info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried the same query with northwind database, where I try to SUM up the freight where customerid's are equal,

You can check the same at [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a9274/1)

I also corrected your query, and now it should work:

You just need to give aliases in the most inner select for sum as `SUM(shipment_cost) as Freight`

```
  SELECT * ,17041 as RecordCount 
  FROM(SELECT TOP 10 * 
       FROM(SELECT TOP 10 orderid, SUM(shipment_cost) as Freight
            FROM TrackingNumbers 
            GROUP BY orderid 
            ORDER BY orderid ASC) 
       SUBSEL ORDER BY orderid DESC)
  PAGESEL ORDER BY orderid ASC
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, table was just something generic and not my actual tablename. So basically what you are saying is my query was correct. It must be something with the application then.

Comment: I get this error when trying to run in Volusion:

`SQL Error: The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.`

TOP is obviously specificed and it works in the SQLFiddle so not sure what's going on.

Comment: You were closest, thanks. Here's the exact answer from Volusion support (had to go through our account rep to get a response jeez): `SELECT orderid, SUM(shipment_cost) as shipment_cost FROM TrackingNumbers GROUP BY orderid ORDER BY orderid ASC`

Answer (score 3):

Use below query

```
SELECT orderid, SUM(shipment_cost) FROM [table] GROUP BY orderid
```

`table` is a SQL keyword

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, table was just something generic and not my actual tablename. So basically what you are saying is my query was correct. It must be something with the application then.